# Refreshing Bearer token with refresh token - problem with request and HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httprequest, dotnet-httpclient

I am making a Web Application. I have a WebAPI which my application connects with via HTTPS.
On the start there is a user logging - WebAPI logs in user after getting data from WebApplication and sends BearerToken and RefreshToken.

Next, my WebApplication stores the tokens. BearerToken is added to every request to WebAPI. After 15 minutes bearer expires. Now, application should get new bearer token using refresh token. I made it in very easy way. All my requests go through this method:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsyncRequest(string uri, string content, HttpMethod method, bool tryReauthorizeOn401 = true)
{
    try
    {
        HttpRequestMessage rm = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
            rm.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, ContentType);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(rm);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized && tryReauthorizeOn401)
        {
            httpClient.CancelPendingRequests();
            bool res = await OnReauthorizeUser();
            if (!res)
                return response;
            return await SendAsyncRequest(uri, content, method, false);
        }

        return response;
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Assert(false, ex.Message);
        throw;
    }            
}
```

This should work like that:

- I send a request
- If I get 401 response and tryReauthorizeOn401 == true, I call `OnReauthorizeUser` event
- In this event handler (which is not shown here) I eventually call again `SendAsyncRequest` with reauthorization data

I expected it to work. But it's not. It turns out that when I call `SendAsynRequest` with reauthorization data, I get TaskCancelletionException. Without any timeout. Just when hitting this: `httpClient.SendAsync(rm);` So my code "returns" to place after `OnReauthorizeUser` (previous call) with res == false.

So, I thought that maybe in some way I distort WebApplication http request lifecycle. I recon that during one request (for example - user clicks link with protected resource) I try send two requests:

- get protected resource
- reauthorize before main request ends

Am I right? How can I avoid such problems? What should I do to:

- when I get 401 response, system should automatically refresh the tokens and call request one more time?

In other words:

- user clicks "Show my documents" link
- Application sends request to WebAPI: `/documents/user/user-id`
- I get response from WebAPI with 401 error
- Application then reauthorizes the user by sending request to WebAPI: `/tokens/refresh/`
- I get response from WebAPI with new tokens (we assume that I will get this)
- Application then sends again request from step two: `/documents/user/user-id`

So I would like to achieve this scenario.
User clicks in the link ONCE and then sees list of his documents. Without necessity to relogin (we assume that he is logged in, bearer token has expired in natural way and refresh token is valid)

Comment: Why call httpClient.CancelPendingRequests()? What happens if you remove that call?

Comment: Actually nothing happens. This was just my attempt.

Comment: Since the exception occurs in the OnReauthorizeUser method, include the code for that method in the question

Comment: No, exception occurs in SendAsyncRequest method that is called "second time" but by OnReauthorizeUser